# How to filter on specific value when subquery

Tags: criteria-filter

I am not a SOQL developer. I do have SQL experience. I have to take over a process that a non-SOQL developer who's no longer here.

I have the following query they wrote:

```
SELECT AccountNumber
FROM Account
WHERE isDeleted = false
      AND 
      Id IN (
              SELECT
              AccountId
              FROM
              AccountTeamMember
              WHERE
              TeamMemberRole = 'Relationship Manager'
              AND
              isDeleted = False
            )
```

I want to test some things and need to filter for a specific group of records, namely, where AccountNumber LIKE '8-%'.  However, if I put that ANYWHERE in the query above, I get an error that it can't be parsed.

I thought it would be as easy as this:

```
SELECT AccountNumber
FROM Account
WHERE AccountNumber LIKE '8-%'
      AND
      isDeleted = false
      AND 
      Id IN (
              SELECT
              AccountId
              FROM
              AccountTeamMember
              WHERE
              TeamMemberRole = 'Relationship Manager'
              AND
              isDeleted = False
            )
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: although OP looks right; check to make sure you are using apostrophes for the quotes around `8-%`

Comment: yes, they are indeed apostrophes.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this syntax:

WHERE Accountnumber LIKE '%yourSearchTerm%';

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Not sure I'm following.  Isn't that what I already tried?

Comment: Yes, that's what I have:
WHERE AccountNumber LIKE '8-%'

The account number will begin with 8, then a dash, then a string so no wildcard before the 8-.